# model averaging with MARSS

Tags: r, state-space-models, model-averaging

I have a large number of MARSS dynamic factor analysis models that, based on AICc, are all competitive for the 'best' model. Is there a way to implement a model averaging process so that I can extract the coefficient estimates of the covariates?